# Store value in Pointers as an Array - C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to make a function like `strcpy` in C++. I cannot use built-in string.h functions because of restriction by our instructor. I have made the following function:

```
    int strlen (char* string)
{
    int len = 0;
    while (string [len] != (char)0) len ++;
    return len;
}

char* strcpy (char* *string1, char* string2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<strlen (string2); i++) *string1[i] = string2[i];
    return *string1;
}
main()
{
       char* i = "Farid";
       strcpy (&i, "ABC ");
       cout<<i;
}
```

But I am unable to set *string1 [i] value. When I try to do so an error appears on screen 'Program has encountered a problem and need to close'.

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: `i` will be in the read only part of the memory and therefore will have a problem. Use `char[] i = "Farid";` instead

Comment: You sure this is a C++, not C class?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - C is a classless society ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Your `strcpy` function is wrong. When you write `*string1[i]` you are actually modifying the first character of the i-th element of an imaginary array of strings. That memory location does not exist and your program segfaults.

Do this instead:

```
char* strcpy (char* string1, char* string2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<strlen (string2); i++) string1[i] = string2[i];
    return string1;
}
```

If you pass a `char*` the characters are already modifiable. Note It is responsibility of the caller to allocate the memory to hold the copy. And the declaration:

```
char* i = "Farid";
```

is not a valid allocation, because the `i` pointer will likely point to read-only memory. Do instead:

```
char i[100] = "Farid";
```

Now `i` holds 100 chars of local memory, plenty of room for your copy:

```
strcpy(i, "ABC ");
```

If you wanted this function to allocate memory, then you should create another one, say `strdup()`:

```
char* strdup (char* string)
{
    size_t len = strlen(string);
    char *n = malloc(len);
    if (!n)
        return 0;
    strcpy(n, string);
    return n;
}
```

Now, with this function the caller has the responsibility to free the memory:

```
char *i = strdup("ABC ");
//use i
free(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this error in the declaration of strcpy: "char* *string1"

I don't think you meant string1 to be a pointer to a pointer to char.

Removing one of the * should word

Answer (score 0):

The code has several issues:

1. You can't assign a string literal to `char*` because the string literal has type `char const[N]` (for a suitable value of `N`) which converts to `char const*` but not to `char*`. In C++03 it was possible to convert to `char*` for backward compatibility but this rule is now gone. That is, your `i` needs to be declared `char const*`. As implemented above, your code tries to write read-only memory which will have undesirable effects.
2. The declaration of `std::strcpy()` takes a `char*` and a `char const*`: for the first pointer you need to provide sufficient space to hold a string of the second argument. Since this is error-prone it is a *bad idea* to use `strcpy()` in the first place! Instead, you want to replicate `std::strncpy()` which takes as third argument the length of the first buffer (actually, I'm never sure if `std::strncpy()` guarantees zero termination or not; you definitely also want to guarantee zero termination).
3. It is a bad idea to use `strlen()` in the loop condition as the function needs to be evaluated for each iteration of the loop, effectively changing the complexity of `strlen()` from linear (*O(N)*) to quadratic (*O(N<sup>2</sup>)*). Quadratic complexity is very bad. Copying a string of 1000 characters takes 1000000 operations. If you want to try out the effect, copy a string with 1000000 characters using a linear and a quadratic algorithm.
4. Your `strcpy()` doesn't add a null-terminator.
5. In C++ (and in C since ~1990) the *implicit `int` rule* doesn't apply. That is, you really need to write `int` in front of `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, a couple of things:

1. you are missing the return type for the `main` function
   declaration.  Not really allowed under the standard.  Some compilers will still allow it, but others will fail on the compile.
2. the way you have your `for` loop structured in
   `strcpy` you are calling your `strlen` function each time through
   the loop, and it is having to re-count the characters in the source
   string.  Not a big deal with a string like "ABC " but as strings get
   longer.... Better to save the value of the result into a variable and use that in the `for` loop
3. Because of the way that you are declaring `i` in
   `main' you are pointing to read-only storage, and will be causing an
   access violation

Look at the other answers here for how to rebuild your code.

Pointer use in C and C++ is a perennial issue. I'd like to suggest the following tutorial from Paul DiLorenzo, ["Learning C++ Pointers for REAL dummies."](http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~pdiloren/C++_Pointers/index.htm).

(This is not to imply that you are a "dummy," it's just a reference to the ",insert subject here> for Dummies" lines of books.  I would not be surprised that the insertion of "REAL" is to forestall lawsuits over trademarked titles)

It is an excellent tutorial.

Hope it helps.